# extract 2 strings from a log file

Tags: bash, string

I have a log file that gets continuously populated; let's state its name is logfile.txt.
In this log file I want to continuously capture sub strings from a single line that contains other strings on the same line using any bash commands.

This is an example of a line in the log file :

```
2023-08-31 09:56:39,925 [G_M80T72|utx:0:ffffac17000b:45253299:64ec7753:79cb0e|chnl:LN1_CRYPTO_IN_MQ_REQ_AMP|id:196010175121000000000002134] WARN  transaction.GeneralTransactionFailureException - GeneralTransactionFailureException Gateway.Transaction[196010175121000000000000067v1], StatusReason[ProcessingFailed/PayloadIntegrityCheckFailed]
```

I want to capture the string1 `LN1` and string2 `CRYPTO_IN_MQ_REQ_AMP` each time the line contains `PayloadIntegrityCheckFailed`.

String1 is always preceded by `chnl:`'and string2 is always followed by a pipe. The 2 strings are always separated by an underscore (but string2 can also contains underscore)
In my example string1=LN1 but it could be like {any letter characters}LN{any number of digits}
String2 can be made of letters and digits

Once string1 and string2 are captured, I would use them as argument in another command like:
`{another_command} string1 string2`

Of course only new entries should then be captured and I don't want to scan the full log continuously, only new lines, so I guess a first start would be to `tail -f` the file, then use some sed magic along with regular expressions.

Would you have an idea how to proceed?

Comment: What do you mean "capture the strings"? `LN1` and `CRYPTO_IN_MQ_REQ_AMP` appear in the same string: `LN1_CRYPTO_IN_MQ_REQ_AMP`. Please [edit] your question and provide the desired output given your example input.

Comment: Sounds like a job for regular expressions: define a pattern with capturing groups, see if it matches the line - if it does, extract the capturing groups.

Answer (score 5):

```bash
$ sed -e '/PayloadIntegrityCheckFailed/!d' -e 's/.*chnl:\([^|]*\).*/\1/' -e 's/_/ /' file
LN1 CRYPTO_IN_MQ_REQ_AMP
```

The `sed` command above discards all lines that does not contain the string `PayloadIntegrityCheckFailed`.  The remaining lines are substituted with whatever comes between `chnl:` and the following `|` character.  The first underscore in that string is replaced by a space character, and the result is outputted.

The second `sed` expression, `s/.*chnl:\([^|]*\).*/\1/`, could probaly be replaced by two simpler substitutions, `s/.*chnl://` and `s/|.*//` (which is not strictly the same thing, but would have the same effect on the example data where the sub-string `chnl:` exists and is later followed by a `|` character).

Instead of a file, the `sed` command could be made to read from the output of `tail -f` for continuous operation.  In that case, you may also want to use line-buffered operation with `sed` (the non-standard `-u` option), if possible.

```bash
tail -f /var/log/some.log | sed -u -e ...as before...
```

To read these strings into variables and use them in some other process, you may read the output of the above pipeline in a `while` loop:

```bash
tail -f ... | sed ... |
while read -r first_string second_string; do
    some-command "$first_string" "$second_string"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple approaches to your issue, each of them using different tools: cat, grep, awk, etc,...

Given your statement "I want to continuously capture sub strings" I guess the right approach would be to use `tail -f` to show the matches on screen or write them to a file.

To print them on screen:

```
tail -f /path/to/your/file.log | grep "PayloadIntegrityCheckFailed" | grep -E "LN1.*CRYPTO_IN_MQ_REQ_AMP"
```

To save results to a file:

```
tail -f /path/to/your/file.log | grep "PayloadIntegrityCheckFailed" | grep -E "LN1.*CRYPTO_IN_MQ_REQ_AMP" >> /tmp/some_file.txt
```

Explanation:

- `tail -f` keeps outputting new lines added to the file.log in real time.
- `grep "PayloadIntegrityCheckFailed"` filters those new lines and ignores the ones not containing the `PayloadIntegrityCheckFailed` string
- grep -E puts grep in REGEXP mode
- The search pattern `"LN1.*CRYPTO_IN_MQ_REQ_AMP"` grabs any lines containing the string `LN1` and also `CRYPTO_IN_MQ_REQ_AMP` somewhere else further ahead in the line.

In your example the `LN1` string seems to be concatenated to `CRYPTO_IN_MQ_REQ_AMP` by a "_" character. Nonetheless as you don't state that clearly in the question I have separated both strings by ".*" any number of characters.